# Do the official Shankaracharya Peethams recognize the validity of Neo-Vedanta?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, neo-vedanta

Do the official [Shankaracharya Peethams](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17912/how-many-mutts-did-adi-shankaracharya-establish-in-his-lifetime) recognize the validity of [Neo-Vedanta](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32037/does-neo-vedanta-cater-to-a-western-audience?noredirect=1#comment96693_32037) as equivalent to traditional Vedanta?

Have any of the Shankaracharya heads of these Peethams said anything regarding Neo-Vedanta?

Comment: How many mutts he really established? Why there are more controversies and myths surrounding around Adi Shankaracharya?

Comment: @NaveenKick I don't know much about the history of Advaita Vedanta, but according to that linked answer, he established 4 or 5 mathams.

Comment: Again and again and again. Same question different clothing...'Neo-Vedanta' is a term given my Western scholars as a way to denigrate ALL Hindus...There are no sects or philosophies that identify themselves as Neo-Vedantists....

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda It's not about denigrating anyone, it's about identifying differences in interpretation in scripture due to passage of time.

Comment: Why are questions asking about Neo Vedanta attracting close votes? What is opinion based in this question? There is a distinction between traditional vedanta and Neo Vedanta given by some advaita websites and this is also answered on our own site. So, what is problem in this topic?

Comment: Just listen to the comments of the shankarcharya of the puri gobardhan math about swami vivekananda and you will understand their stand

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee I don't understand Hindi. Can you tell me what they say please?

Comment: Demeaning Swami Vivekananda

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Ok, I see.

Comment: The question is non-trivial to answer because the term 'equivalent' has many meanings. (Also I presume you really mean neo-Advaita vs traditional Advaita.) 
Equivalent in what way? In the result that is achieved if one pursues on that path? In the lifestyle choices that may bemade by a follower? IMU, the fundamental difference between Neo-Advaita and traditional Advaita is the lifestyle choices - definition of nitya-anushthana, dharma, karma, srauta/smarta practices. Traditional Advaita insists on the following of Vedic dharma whereas Neo/Western Advaita isn't strict about it.